# How to show Laravel database data in Ionic

Tags: mysql, ionic-framework, laravel-5, fetch-api

I am integrating an Ionic Framework with Laravel. In MYSQL table there is a option table(master-table) which is having certain options says Table, chairs, suite case etc etc.

I am not getting how can I fetch the data of table in ionic view to display all the options in dropdown.

When I was developing web Application as its in laravel, so in blade view I can directly able to fetch it.But I am not getting an Idea how to do it in ionic view, as I am consuming API services.
Please guide me for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For safety reasons it is usually best practice to create a rest api and call the endpoints via the http module to access your database. See the link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

If you choose to access the database that means you would have to store credentials in the ionic app which is quite dangerous.